# Get value from dynamic array (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a method that returns array in a way like this:

```
int *compare() {
    int result[2] = {10, 20};
    return result;
}
```

With the code `int *match = compare();` , who do I get the `10` or the `20`?

Comment: You can't, because you are returning a pointer to a local variable that goes out of scope, invaliding the pointer, as soon as `compare()` exits.  To do what you are attempting, you would have to declare `result` as `static`, for instance. Or move it to global memory.  Either way, then you can safely use normal pointer arithmetic operations, like accessing `match[0]` and `match[1]`.

Comment: Undefined Behaviour - you are returning a pointer to variable that has gone out of scope.

Comment: and thats not a dynamic array either

Comment: You can do int match = *compare(); in which case you get 10, or

Answer (score 3):

With C++, you really should prefer to use a standard container such as [`std::vector<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).  Doing that, your sample code might be

```
std::vector<int> compare() {
    std::vector<int> result {10, 20};
    return result;
}
```

---

If you *really* want to return a pointer (why?) at least pass the ownership back to the caller using [`std::unique_ptr<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).  That code looks like

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> compare() {
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> result(new int[] { 10, 20 });
    return result;
}
```

But using `std::vector<>` is **much** preferred.

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is undefined behavior, if not a compiler error.
your array is on the stack and is local to your function. It goes out of scope when the function returns and is gone.

You'd need to allocate it on the heap using operator new for it to make any sense. If you do, it is recommended you return a std::unique_ptr so callers know there are dealing with an allocated object and cleanup is handled if the return if not grabbed.

Comment: "is on the stack" technically it's in Automatic storage. You are unlikely to see an instance of it without deliberately looking, but C++ can be implemented just fine without a stack or a heap.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
int *compare(int result[])
{
     result[0] = 10;
     result[1] = 20;
     return result;
   }

 int main()
 {
    int result[2];
    int *match = compare(result);
    cout << *match << endl;
    cout << *(match + 1) << endl;
 }
```

You can't return the address of a local variable because whatever is inside that variable goes away after the return statement.

Comment: Sure you can. It happens all the time.

Comment: whatever is inside of result goes away after the end of *compare so there is no point in returning the address of result since everything inside it disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

> You must use one of the following dynamic allocation methods;

- **malloc()** - Allocates requested size of bytes and returns a pointer first byte of allocated space.
- **calloc()** - Allocates space for an array elements, initializes to zero and then returns a pointer to memory.
- **new** - keyword only cpp not c

---

```
int *compare() {
     int *result =  (int*)calloc(2,sizeof(int)); // or cpp -> new int[2];
     result[0] = 10;
     result[1] = 20;
     return result;
}
```